# Windows 7 Home Premium can ping Server 2012 IP & name, but server isn't listed in network and can't map shares

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, windows-server-2012

This seems to be a fairly common issue with many different twists.

We've got an odd environment.  A 2012 Server with some Windows 7 Pro machines but more Home Premium machines, and an old 2008 Server hanging around.

One machine sharing the same workgroup as it's peers can't identify the server.  We can ping the server by IP address and by server name.  We cannot see the server nor map a share based on either name or IP address.

I've booted the machine up with Puppy Linux and was able access the server share that way, so I'd guess that would eliminate a lot of hardware issues.

I tried adding a workgroup share on another machine that has identical setting and it wouldn't give access either.  At least that machine shows up via discovery.  That seems to be a clue?  Network discovery is turned on, the firewall is turned off, and everything should be easily within view, but isn't...

Machines that connect and the machine that does not share identical (except IP) ipconfig /all readouts.

NetBios on IPv4 has been turned on.  Client for MS Networks is running.

Many features have been toggled without response and sometimes just as a shot in the dark:  Home/Office network type, home sharing, ...

Utilizing wireless networking provided the same results.

We tried adding a user account and then connecting, but ended up with the same results.

No luck.  The machine had previously connected to the network shares without issue.  This seems to have originated with a QuickBooks update - restore had no effect though.

Any ideas?  This seems like something that ought to be easy, but not so much so far.

Comment: Some people with similar issues found that the Workstation service was turned off.  This doesn't seem to be the issue in this case.